# Inline virtual function when called from another virtual function?

Tags: c++, gcc, inline, virtual-functions

I have a class with two virtual member functions: `foo` and `wrapper`. `foo` is short and fast, and `wrapper` contains a loop that calls `foo` many times. My hope is that there is some way to inline the calls to `foo` *inside the wrapper function*, even when called from a pointer to an object:

```
MyClass *obj = getObject();
obj->foo(); // As I understand it, this cannot be inlined. That's okay.
obj->wrapper(); // Nor will this. However, I hope that the machine code
                // for the wrapper function will contain inlined calls to
                // foo().
```

**Essentially, I want the compiler to generate multiple versions of the wrapper function -- one for each possible class -- and inline calls to the appropriate `foo`, which should be possible since the object type is determined before picking which `wrapper` function to execute.** Is this possible? Do any compilers support this optimization?

**Edit:** I appreciate all of the feedback and answers so far, and I may end up picking one of them. However, most responses ignore the last part of my question where I explain why I think this optimization should be feasible. That is really the crux of my question and I am still hoping someone can address that.

**Edit 2**: I picked Vlad's answer since he both suggested the popular workaround and partially addressed my proposed optimization (in the comments of David's answer). Thanks to everyone who wrote an answer -- I read them all and there wasn't a clear "winner".

Also, I found an academic paper that proposes an optimization very similar to what I was suggesting: http://www.ebb.org/bkuhn/articles/cpp-opt.pdf.

Comment: The compiler will probably know enough to optimize the virtual function lookup into a one time hit.

Comment: True, but that still leaves the (larger?) overhead of a non-inline function call, right?

Comment: Yes, but short of machine code instrumentation it's probably not possible to make this happen.

Comment: Why? I tried to explain why I think it should be possible in the last part of my question -- does that make any sense to you?

Comment: It might be possible to do this, but it's hard to say.  I rather doubt compilers will generate code that behaves like this because it isn't guaranteed to work in the absences of other subclasses of the classes you're writing.

Comment: No, your assumptions are wrong. The fact that `A::foo` is being executed doesn't mean that the dynamic type of `*this` is `A`.

Comment: The compiler already has lots of optimizations for calling (plus the safe guards to validate that it is correct). If the call can be inlined safely and it is cheaper to inline the function (according to the compilers heuristics) then it will.

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, this may be relevant to what you are trying to accomplish:  have you considered a template-based compile-time approach?  Given your bolded text containing "I want the compiler to generate multiple versions of the wrapper function -- one for each possible class".. that really sounds like templates to me.

Comment: @Cheezy, yes I have considered that. I need to be able to keep objects of sibling classes in a std::vector, so I don't think compile-time polymorphism will work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In certain cases, compiler can determine the virtual dispatch behavior in compile-time and perform non-virtual function invocation or even inline the function. It can only do that if it can figure out that your class is the "top" in inheritance chain or those two functions are not otherwise overloaded. Oftentimes, this is simply impossible, especially if you don't have late time optimization enabled for the whole program.

Unless you want to check the results of your compiler's optimizations, your best bet would be not to use a virtual function in the inner loop at all. For example, something like this:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        foo_impl();
    }

    virtual void bar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ∞; ++i) {
            foo_impl();
        }
    }

  private:
    void foo_impl() { /* do some nasty stuff here */ }
};
```

But in that case you clearly give up the idea that somebody may come in, inherit from your class and throw in their own implementation of "foo" to be called by your "bar". They will essentially will need to re-implement both.

On the other hand, it smells a bit like a premature optimization. Modern CPUs will most likely "lock" your loop, predict the exit from it and execute the same µOPs over and over, even if your method is virtually virtual. So I'd recommend you carefully determine this to be a bottleneck before spending your time optimizing it.

Answer (score 2):

No, the function call will not be inlined if performed through a pointer or reference (this includes the `this` pointer). A new type can be created that extends from your current type and overrides `foo` without overriding `wrapper`.

If you want to enable the compiler to inline your function, you must disable virtual dispatch for that call:

```
void Type::wrapper() {
    Type::foo();            // no dynamic dispatch
}
```

Comment: Dave, it may. These days compilers are a bit smarter than a toaster :)

Comment: @Vlad: When the function is compiled it does not have visibility for the whole program, so it cannot know whether there is a most derived type that overrides `foo` (and not `wrapper`). Even with whole program optimization, you can load code from a dynamic library and that could have more types. This is one of the reasons for the new `final` contextual non-keyword in C++11. In that context, because the language guarantees it could, but only if `foo` is tagged `final` (and I have not seen that used anywhere yet)

Comment: Yes and no. It depends on symbol visibility, really.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: *How* How can the compiler, when generating code for a translation unit know whether in a different translation unit, possibly in a loaded dynamic library, maybe in a manually loaded dynamic library there will not be a type that extends this one? It is not theoretically impossible to implement in some subcases, but I'd like to know of any compiler that does this. (Also I am not sure that *symbol visibility* is  the right term)

Comment: Dave, the optimization is performed on a later stage, not when generating code for a translation unit, but when generating code for an executable. There, compiler may know the inheritance scheme, as well as visibility, and perform all of the necessary optimizations. Vtables are one thing, it can also re-arrange parameters, re-allocate registers etc. It's been quite a while since I looked at those techniques, so can't give you specific references unfortunately. But you may poke around clang and gcc internals to figure out.

Comment: Apparently I've asked a question that it is a bit out of my depth :). To the extent that I understand these comments, it seems like the optimization I want, if it is possible at all, would have to happen at link time rather than compile time.

Comment: @DrewFrank: Yes, and even at link time it might not be possible under the conditions listed above. To be able to apply the optimization the compiler/linker must know that it is impossible to have a type that derives the current type in the program. The solutions offered either in Vlad's answer or here tackle that in different ways: make a non-virtual function and call that or explicitly disable dynamic dispatch in this call as in my answer. Both of them solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the following hierarchy:

```
class Base
{
    virtual void foo();
    virtual void wrapper();
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
    virtual void foo() { cout << "Derived1::foo"; }
    virtual void wrapper() { foo(); }
};

class Derived2: public Derived1
{
    virtual void foo() { cout << "Derived2::foo"; }
};

Base * p1 = new Derived1;
p1->wrapper();  // calls Derived1::wrapper which calls Derived1::foo
Base * p2 = new Derived2;
p2->wrapper();  // calls Derived1::wrapper which calls Derived2::foo
```

Can you see the problem? Derived1::wrapper *must* call Derived2::foo. It can't know until runtime whether it will be calling Derived1::foo or Derived2::foo, so there's no way to inline it.

If you want to insure that inlining is possible, make sure that the function you want to inline isn't virtual. It seems from your description that this might be possible, if every class in the hierarchy reimplements both `foo` and `wrapper`. A function doesn't need to be virtual to be overridden.

Comment: This is true, **but** there's an option that he wants `Derived1::wrapper` to call `Derived1::foo` regardless if it's the most derived class or not. (it's not clear though)

Comment: @Mark: Good example. In this case, I want the compiler to autogenerate two functions for me: Derived1::wrapper_calledFromDerived1 and Derived1::wrapper_calledFromDerived2. Then the vtable for objects of type Derived1 would point to the first of these, and objects of type Derived2 point to the second. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is not accurate. `virtual` functions **can** be inlined, but only if the compiler knows the static type of the object with certainty - and thus have the guarantee that polymorphism works.

For example:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
    }
};
struct B
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo(); //this can be inlined
    A* pa = new A;
    pa->foo(); //so can this
}

void goo(A* pa)
{
    pa->foo() //this probably can't
}
```

That said, it appears that in your case this can't happen. What you can do is have another non-`virtual` function that actually implements the functionality and call it statically, so the call gets resolved at compile-time:

```
class MyClass
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void wrapper() = 0;
};

class Derived : MyClass
{
    void fooImpl()
    {
       //keep the actual implementation here
    }
    virtual void foo()
    {
       fooImpl();
    }
    virtual void wrapper()
    {
       for ( int i = 0 ; i < manyTimes ; i++ )
          fooImpl(); //this can get inlined
    }
};
```

or simply `Derived::foo()` as pointed out by @avakar.

Comment: Note that you can call a virtual function without dynamic dispatch: `Derived::foo()`. That should remove the need for `fooImpl`.

Comment: I do not know the type until runtime, so Derived::foo() is not an option. The fooImpl() patter seems like a reasonable workaround.

Comment: @DrewFrank it's the same thing really. You call `Derived::foo` from `Derived::wrapper`, not from the same class, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is `virtual` and its type is not indicate until runtime, so how you expect compiler to inline code of some class into it?

In some similar situation I had 2 functions: `foo` that is virtual and `foo_impl` that is normal function and will be called from `foo` and `wrapper`